# Problems with floating-point additions. Ignoring some small values

Tags: math, cuda, floating-point

I'm looking up a book about CUDA.

On the chapter which explains the floating points of CUDA, I found something odd.

The book says that (1.00 * 1) + (1.00 * 1) + (1.00 * 0.01) + (1.00* 0.01) = 10. All the numbers are binaries. 0.01 refers to decimal 0.25.

So, in decimal serially adding 1 + 1 + 0.25 + 0.25 results in 2.

The book says why this happens ; after doing 1+1, **it will ignore +0.25 since it's too small compared to the other operand(the result of 1+1, 2).**

After this, they say that doing 0.25 + 0.25 + 1 + 1 will produce 2.5, since 0.5 is considered enough to be added with 1.

What is the meaning of this? How could the processor judge that 0.25 is too small compared to 2? Are there obvious standards for this?

Comment: It looks like implied coercion from floating point to integer is occurring; then rounding based on the usual rules is being applied. Perhaps you can post a link to the exact reference you saw, so that it can be parsed more completely.

Comment: 1) This is not CUDA-specific; this is how IEEE-754 floating point math works. 2) This portion of the book seems to be explaining how limited precision works. For the sake of clarity, unrealistically low number of bits in mantissa is used in this artificial example. Real-world floating point formats, such as IEEE-754 float, will of course correctly calculate 1+1+0.25+0.25 as 2.5.

Comment: The book is Programming massively parallel processors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example implicitly declares a binary floating point format, which has an arbitrary precision exponent, but only 2 bits in the mantissa. All numbers are of format 1.xx * 2^n.

When one performs floating point addition, one must de-normalize or scale the arguments to have the same exponent.

```
   0.25 =   1e-2 = 0.5e-1 = 0.25e0 = 0.125e1
   2.00 =   1e1
```

But in the same base 0.125 = 0.001, which can't be represented with 2 bits of mantissa after the decimal.

Even if we add word length, it doesn't matter:

```
  0.25 = 0.001000000000000000 (e=1)
  2.00 = 1.000000000000000000 (e=1)
  ---------------------------------
  2.25 = 1.001000000000000000 (e=1)
           ^^
```

The result will be those two bits after the decimal point, i.e. (1.00e1) = 2.

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism by which all of this works (or does not) is that if you add together numbers some of the precision of the smaller one (in absolute value) is lost. This comes from the finite precision at which operations are performed.

The smaller the gap between the numbers you sum, the smaller the loss.

In your case, when you do 1+1, you get 2. Then 0.25 is *10 times smaller* than 2. Your book indicates that this is such a big factor that 0.25 is so small that it is like adding 0 (which is an approximation of 0.25 at the order of magnitude set by 2). The same thing happens with the second 0.25: it adds nothing.

When you start with 0.25+0.25, you are adding two numbers with the same size, so you get a perfect 0.5. Then when you add 1, you are adding two numbers *with a ratio of only 2*: this is much smaller than the factor of 10 in the previous case, and your book says it can be done, so you get a total of 1.5. Then there is the remaining term 1: you are adding 1.5 and 1; the factor between both is *just 1.5*, so, again this can be done, and you get 2.5.